# Can we constitute a network barely with switches?

Tags: networking, ip, switch-statement, router, arp

If I set all the ips connect to a switch with the same subnet ip, can they communicate with each other with ips?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer networking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I set all the ips connect to a switch with the same subnet ip, can they communicate with each other with ips?

I think you're asking whether you can put all your computers and switch virtual IP in the same IP subnet and get them to communicate.

The answer is yes... as long as all hosts are in the same subnet, and attached to the same ethernet broadcast domain (the switch) they will be able to reach each other with IP.